# What json response to send if count total is equal to zero

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to display some data only if the total is greater than zero. And I am using axios and want to send back a json response. So, the `<li>` should only show if there is a value greater than 0 otherwise nothing should show. If I don't send back a response or I have just `res.status(200)` then in the network tab I can see that it just stays in a pending state with provisional headers shown, and eventually an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` message.

```
exports.getPendingCountSide = (req, res, next) => {
  Product.countDocuments({ userId: req.user, status: "pending" })
    .then(pending => {
      if (pending > 0) {
        const pendingTotal =
          '<li><a href="/account/pending">Pending <span class="nav-tag yellow">' +
          pending +
          "</span></a></li>";
        res.status(200).json({ html: pendingTotal });
      } else {
        res.status(200);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning an empty string if the total is not greater than zero?

```
res.status(200).json({ html: '' });
```

Comment: Hey, that actually works. I had tried something similar without the html part inside as I thought that would leave a gap in the visual but great, thank you!